# iterm2 profile environment

Tags: iterm

Iterm2 profiles have the general option to specify a command to run in the profile, such as ssh.  What environment does this command run in?  It doesn't seem to be the environment of the default shell.

Comment: Run the command, as you described, `echo $0`. What output do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Like Terminal app it runs it directly from the app not using a shell at all.

In macOS unlike X windows apps do not run from inside a shell so there is nothing to inherit.

If you want to run something that uses say zsh's environment you need to choose command in the Profile settings and enter the command - but this is the environment on the other machine.

e.g. to run nano

`zsh nano`

As for ssh by default it picks up its environment from the machine you ssh into not the one you are running iTerm on.